# Is this a pararhyme?

Tags: poetry, wilfred-owen

"Halted", "Fed" and "Eased" from first stanza of "Spring Offensive" by Wilfred Owen.

> Halted against the shade of a last hill
>   They fed, and, lying easy, were at ease;
>   And, finding comfortable chests and knees
>   Carelessly slept.

Comment: What makes you think those are pararhymes? "Shade" and "fed" would be an example of a pararhyme; no doubt accidental, seeing as the poem is composed with end rhymes rather than internal rhymes.

Comment: Having the same three letters at the end does not a pararhyme make; *take, tack, tech, tic* are pararhymes, while *dough, laugh, ugh* are not.

Comment: I can't see the word *eased* in the excerpt, only *easy* and *ease*.

Answer (score 5):

### No.

A [pararhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pararhyme) is when two or more words (usually at the ends of lines or at least phrases) have **the same pattern of consonants but different vowels**: for example, "hill/hall/hell" or "fed/food/fad". The words you've highlighted - "halted", "fed", and "eased" - do not have the same pattern of consonants,  namely HLTD, FD, and ZD. So no, they don't form a pararhyme.

The only really similar thing about these three words is that they all end in "ed". But since the "e" is silent anyway, that's not really enough for any sort of rhyme.